# No library trees found in 'lib.loc' when installing custom package

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2, install.packages

I am making a package for functions that I developed for a specific application at work. I was using a guide to make the package using devtools and roxygen2. see guide here https://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/

When finished following the steps I used the install() feature and I get this error.

```
* installing *source* package 'subOpti' ...
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
Warning in library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, 
logical.return = TRUE) :
  no library trees found in 'lib.loc'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
Warning in library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, 
logical.return = TRUE) :
  no library trees found in 'lib.loc'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
* removing '\\server/users/lgallaway/My Documents/R/win-
library/3.3/subOpti'
```

My lib location is on a server and I choose my package location in a different section of a fileserver. I thought that maybe the server locations were an issue, so I moved the package locally but that just generated a separate error.

Comment: What command did you run exactly that generated this output? What OS are you using?

Comment: Is this an error that might show up if I did not have write privileges? I can install packages to this location through CRAN with admittedly an occasional issue, but maybe its different with a package like this?

Comment: I used install("subOpti") from the parent directory of the folder I had my package stored in. I am using Windows 7 enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

Well I took the files home and followed the same process that was highlighted in the guide above and it worked no issue.  I am assuming the issue is that I don't have write permissions to the network lib location.